# sails.js modify model before create

Tags: javascript, database, sails.js

I have a data sent from the front-end to my controller and I need to modify the data before create action happens. I don't want to write a custom create action, the Blueprint API's create action is what I need. I'm just wondering what is the correct place to do such data modification. Basically I need to populate an attribute of model before the saving it in database.

Comment: do it at you front end javascript.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [`beforeCreate`](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/lifecycle-callbacks) lifecycle callback in your model to modify the values before an entry is created in the database.

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        // your models attributes
    },

    beforeCreate: function (values, cb) {
        // make your changes
        return cb();
    }
}
```

You could write a controller action to do this

```
// api/controllers/ModelController.js
// controller actions for api/models/Model.js

module.exports = {
    create: function (req, res) {
        var options = request.body;

        // modify request body
        Model
            .create(options)
            .exec(function (err, obj) {
                if (err) { return res.serverError(); }
                return res.json(obj);
            });
    }
};
```

Or you could [override](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/blueprint-api#?overriding-blueprints) the blueprint create action, by creating a file `api/blueprints/create.js` and do your modifications there. It will be similar to the controller above. But this will affect the create action for all models, so probably not what you want.

Comment: I do somewhat agree with this, but in my case I don't want model to be aware of it, I rather do it in controller.

Comment: But in your question you say you don't want to write a custom create action o_0

Answer (score -4):

You can try to write some js code in your client-side, to modify your data before the create action.
Good luck for you!